# Chaining operations in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm running strings through a series of operations, most of which are regexes, some of which aren't. I'm wondering if there is some syntactic structure similar to monads that would allow me to make sequential application of functions 'prettier'.

I.E, for functions f,g,h,I and input string s:

```
f(s) -> g -> h -> i
```

Rather than

```
i g h f(s)
```

Comment: https://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/currying-in-python/ is pretty comprehensive. It shows how currying can be done in python, but it's not as natural as something like haskell.

Comment: Maybe [Pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a little helper function to do something similar:

```
import functools as ft   # Py3 reduce
def func(arg, *funcs):
    return ft.reduce(lambda a, f: f(a), funcs, arg)

>>> f = lambda x: x+1
>>> g = lambda x: x*2
>>> h = lambda x: x**2
>>> func(4, f, g, h)
100
```

Or a helper class:

```
class Func(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, *funcs):
        return ft.reduce(lambda a, f: f(a), funcs, self.arg)

>>> Func(4)(f, g, h)
100
```

But I'm not quite sure why this is any better than:

```
>>> func = lambda x: h(g(f(x)))
>>> func(4)
100
```